# Postgres Get all possible column combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I got a View of items in Postgres that looks like this:

| id | brand_id | category_id | color_id | material_id | pattern_id | style_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 100 | 101 | null | 101 |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 101 | 102 | null | 102 |
| 2 | 101 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 102 | null |
| 2 | 101 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 103 | null |
| 3 | 105 | 101 | null | 103 | 104 | null |
| 4 | 101 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 103 | 105 |

I need all DISTINCT possible combinations (excluding item_id) but forming groups that not always will include all columns.

Example of combinations for the First Row (but I need the same for all items without getting duplicated groups):

| brand_id | category_id | color_id | material_id | pattern_id | style_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | null | null | null | null | null |
| null | 101 | null | null | null | null |
| null | null | 100 | null | null | null |
| null | null | null | 101 | null | null |
| null | null | null | null | null | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | null | null | null | null |
| 100 | null | 100 | null | null | null |
| 100 | null | null | 101 | null | null |
| 100 | null | null | 101 | null | null |
| 100 | null | null | 101 | null | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 | null | null | null |
| 100 | 101 | null | 101 | null | null |
| 100 | 101 | null | null | null | 101 |

I tried a CROSS JOIN with the original categories tables but I get a enormous table of combinations and also I don't get the groups of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 categories, I get the combinations including ALL six categories

Comment: What is the logic for not including a group of (100,101,100,101,...,...)?

Comment: I need to get statistics for multiple combinations for example: get all the ownership of brand_id = 100 and color_id = 100 only. Or all purchases from pattern_id = 100 AND material_id =  101 (The combination are endless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CUBE subclause for GROUP BY, which produces the following output for your first row:

---

```
    select 
100 brand_id,   101 category_id,    100 color_id,   
101 material_id,    null pattern_id,    101 style_id
    group by
    cube (brand_id, category_id,    color_id,   material_id ,pattern_id ,style_id);
```

| brand_id | category_id | color_id | material_id | pattern_id | style_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 |  | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 |  |  | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  |  | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  |  | 101 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 100 |  | 100 |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 | 100 | 101 |  |  |
| 100 |  | 100 | 101 |  |  |
| 100 |  | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  | 101 | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  | 101 | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  | 101 |  | 101 |  | 101 |
|  | 101 | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | 101 |
| 100 |  |  |  |  | 101 |
| 100 |  | 100 |  |  | 101 |
|  |  | 100 |  |  | 101 |
|  |  | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 |  | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
|  | 101 |  |  |  | 101 |
|  | 101 | 100 |  |  | 101 |
|  | 101 | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  |  | 101 |  |  |
|  |  |  | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  | 100 |  |  |  |
|  |  | 100 |  |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 |  |  | 101 |
|  | 101 |  |  |  |  |
|  | 101 |  |  |  | 101 |
|  | 101 | 100 |  |  | 101 |
|  |  | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  |  | 100 | 101 |  |  |
|  |  | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
|  | 101 |  | 101 |  |  |
|  | 101 |  | 101 |  |  |
|  | 101 |  | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 |  | 101 |  | 101 |
|  | 101 | 100 |  |  |  |
|  | 101 | 100 |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 | 100 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 100 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 |  |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 |  | 101 |  |  |
| 100 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 100 |  |  | 101 |  |  |
| 100 |  |  | 101 |  |  |
| 100 |  |  | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 101 |
| 100 |  |  |  |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 |  |  |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 |  |  |  | 101 |
|  | 101 |  |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 |  |  |  |  |
| 100 | 101 |  | 101 |  |  |
| 100 | 101 |  | 101 |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 | 101 |  | 101 |
|  |  | 100 |  |  |  |
| 100 |  | 100 |  |  |  |
| 100 |  | 100 |  |  | 101 |
| 100 | 101 | 100 |  |  | 101 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Didn't know about the CUBE subclause, very useful! Thanks